# How to add Raylib to VS code?

Tags: c++, raylib

I am a beginner at c++ and I would like to use raylib with vscode instead of using notpad++.
does anybody know how to add raylib to vscode.

Comment: thank you for your solution but what file must I copy the VS code file from Raylib into?

Comment: Please refer to the official guide on this very topic : [Using raylib in VSCode](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Using-raylib-in-VSCode).

Comment: @ josephi I don't get what are you asking in the above comment. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: when it says "Copy the VSCode folder (and all its contents) from raylib/projects/VSCode (from your installed directory) to your desired project location." i dont know where the project location is

Comment: is it a project that you make?

Comment: Yeah, you first need to create a folder in which you want to keep your project source. There you need to move the downloaded `.vscode` folder and the make files.

Comment: I am still having trouble. would you mind sending me a video on it please.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: i am on windows 10

Comment: I am unable to find any proper video, please consider going through the answer I just posted. If you face any difficulty then please add a comment on the answer.

Comment: ok, thank you brc-dd.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the official guide on this topic : [Using raylib in VSCode](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Using-raylib-in-VSCode).

I am re-writing the instructions mentioned in the link (in simplified form) :

1. Install Raylib from the [official release binaries](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/releases/latest) (Install using `raylib_installer_v300.mingw.exe` on Windows).
2. Install [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
3. Now create a folder (say `my_project`) in which you want to keep the files of your project.
4. Download files from this [link](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/projects/VSCode) and copy them into the folder you made at above step.

This should result in the following structure :

```
my_project
 |- .vscode
 |    |- c_cpp_properties.json
 |    |- launch.json
 |    |- settings.json
 |    |- tasks.json
 |- Makefile
 |- Makefile.Android
 |- main.c
 |- main.code-workspace
```

5. Modify the paths inside in the files if `gcc.exe` is not there in `C:/raylib/mingw/bin/`.
6. Install [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).
7. Then open VSCode in the folder you made (right-click on folder and open with VSCode).
8. Open `main.c` file, press press F5. Your code should compile and run on debug mode.

If you face any problem in following the step by step instructions then please add a comment.

Comment: I can't get it to work so I will just use the IDE that Raylib comes with but thank you anyways

Comment: @josephi Can you tell me any specific problem that's occurring to you during the setup?

Comment: when I put all the files in the folder they don't show up in vscode

Comment: @josephi Are you sure you are opening the whole folder and not just a file? Open VSCode and press `Ctrl + K` followed by `Ctrl + O`. Then choose the `my_project` folder to open. It will open the workspace for you. There on left side you must see `.vscode` folder and `main.c` files.

Comment: @brc-dd Could you elaborate more about Step 1? I downloaded the raylib file (`raylib-4.2.0_win64_mingw-w64.zip` in my case) but I'm not sure how to install it. Where do you find  `raylib_installer_v300.mingw.exe` and how do you use it to install the raylib file?

Comment: @Ogiad Check the releases, there will be a file named `raylib_installer_vXXX.mingw.exe`. (version will be different depending on the release).

Comment: Try adding C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin to your PATH environment variable and then restart whichever terminal you're using. This did the trick for me.

Comment: @brc-dd, Thanks to your help, I can now run the example code (rotating cube) with F5 key. However, when I try to compile the code with 'Run code' , I get an error message saying "fatal error: raylib.h: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach to start using raylib in Visual Studio Code is to download a pre-configured template.

If you have raylib installed in the default directory on the C drive (C:\raylib), this template should work seamlessly without any additional modifications.

https://github.com/educ8s/Raylib-CPP-Starter-Template-for-VSCODE

To get started, simply download the raylib template and double-click on the main.code-workspace file. This will open Visual Studio Code with the project loaded.

In addition, make sure you have the C++ extension installed in Visual Studio Code.

Press F5 on your keyboard and you should see a bouncing ball example.