# Compilation of Raylib function fails on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, compiler-errors, raylib

I'm getting an error in the compilation of a C file that heavily uses Raylib function.

### Environment

- OS: Windows 10
- IDE: Visual Studio Code
- Raylib version: 4.2.0 (win64, mingw)

### Sanity check of Raylib installation

Following the discussions in [How to add Raylib to VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791456/how-to-add-raylib-to-vs-code),  I successfully compiled an example code: `main.c` in this [link](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/projects/VSCode/.vscode). That means, the Raylib function is correctly installed, and the path to the source libraries is also set correctly.

### Compilation of my code

Using the set of JSON files (`c_cpp_properties.json`, `launch.json`, `settings.json`, `tasks.json`) used in the example code, I'm trying to compile my code. There are several ways to compile code on VS code.

- Compilation by F5 key

  In this case, I get the following messages on my terminal:

  ```
  Executing task: C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib PROJECT_NAME=MyCode OBJS=MyCode.c BUILD_MODE=DEBUG 

  mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
  ```

  It seems like I need to make a Makefile to configure the compilation but I have no idea how to write it. I tried using the Makefile in [link](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/projects/VSCode/.vscode) but it caused an error. I probably need to make a code-specific Makefile but I have no clue.
- Compilation by command #1

  I also tried to compile my code by running the following command on VS code terminal:

  ```
  gcc MyCode.c lib/librarylib.a -o MyCode
  ```

  but I got the following error message:

  ```
  fatal error: raylib.h: No such file or directory
  ```

  The header file `raylib.h` is not recognized even though I used the same header in the example code I compiled earlier. The path to the header is also set properly.
- Compilation by command #2

  To set the path to the file location of `raylib.h` more explicitly, I used the following command instead:

  ```
  gcc -Wall -IC:\raylib\raylib\src MyCode.c MyCode.exe -l/librarylib -o a.out
  ```

  Note that the `C:\raylib\raylib\src` is the path to a folder that contains `raylib.h`. This time I got the following error:

  ```
  gcc.exe: error: MyCode.c: No such file or directory
  gcc.exe: error: MyCode.exe: No such file or directory
  ```

### Some clues ...

I got this code from another guy. The code was originally developed on M1 mac, and it was compiled successfully by the following command:

```
clang -framework CoreVideo -framework IOKit -framework Cocoa -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL lib/libraylib.a MyCode.c -o MyCode
```